# log4net cant insert data to custom column

Tags: log4net

Writing db for base lognet columns fine, but I added another column called "clientIp" and set data to Ilog object bofore log but it writes same data with Message column to ClintIp column.. here my config and file and db screenshot:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      ...
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[ClientIp]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @clientip)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
     ...
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@clientip" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
```

[image]
and my logger class:

```
public static class Logger
    {

        private static ILog log  {get; set;}
        static Logger()
        {
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }
        public static void Error(object msg, string userip)
        {
            log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ClientIp"] = userip;
            if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
            {
                log.Error(msg);
            }
        }
```

whats is problem here ?

**EDITED:**
Its obvious, it writes db with for message and clientip with given parameter: for exmp: log.Error('Your Ip is::1'); how can I tell log4net use log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ClientIp"] for ClientIp column and log.error(message) for Message column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct, it should be:

```
public static void Error(object msg, string userip)
    {
        log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ClientIp"] = userip;
        if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
        {
            log.Error(msg); //<----Here is your error
        }
    }
```

And add in the ip column:

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@clientip" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" >
          <conversionPattern value="%property{ClientIp}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

Comment: I dont understand, then how can I post log to db ? you mean I shouldnt pass parameter to log.Error() function. but it expects paramters(not overloaded for non param function)..What should I do

Comment: I edited but still same.. both Message and Client ip data has msg data

Comment: see edit, I added the conversion pattern for the column

Comment: mans like you is the reason why I love this job and stackoverflow!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else, I had the same problem: the data in my added column was "somewhat" repeated from the Message column.

For example, I was simply logging "accessed home page" as the message.  My added column had "accessed home pageac" showing up in it.

My first mistake was having a value attribute after the layout type:

Removing the value attribute from above prevented the data from being duplicated in the added column, but now the column was null.

My second mistake was that for some unknown reason, log4net does NOT like 'machinename'.  I don't know if the problem is the column name, or the parameter name, but I changed all instances of 'machinename' to 'server' (including renaming the column in the DB of course), and it all started working.

EDIT

Ok so I think I just realized that the problem was the Properties value is case sensitive, so I was using .Properites["MachineName"] but should have been using .Properties["machinename"].